# Rails 5 check if record exist in belongs_to relations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have 3 models Account, Plan and User (And I can not modify the relations model structure, but add scopes or methods)

```
Account 
belongs_to :plan

Plan
belongs_to :user

User
has_may :plans
```

I want to know if EXISTS an account with a specific user_id

Account.exists?…….. //here is my problem

Comment: The accounts table in the database does not have a user_id column in it. You have to first get all the plans belonging to an account, and then you have to check if those plans have the specific user you are seeking. pls clarify your question. also you want to traverse between models, I suggest adding a `has_many` relation between the models. I recommend reviewing the following if you are not familiar with that concept: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would join the database tables by using `joins` which results in a `INNER JOIN` in SQL and than add a condition for the `user_id` in question:

```
Account.joins(plan: :user).where(users: { id: user_id }).exists?
```

Read about [`joins` in the Rails Guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-nested-associations-single-level).

Answer (score 0):

You can create indirect associations which link Account and User through the Plan model:

```
class Account < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :plan
  has_one :user, through: :plan
end

class Plan < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_may :plans
  has_many :accounts, through: :plans
end
```

This will let you query:

```
Account.joins(:user)
       .where(users: { id: user_id })
       .exists?
```

ActiveRecord will automatically handle joining through the plans table.

See the Rails guides:

- [The has_many :through Association](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)
- [The has_one :through Association](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-one-through-association)
- [Specifying Conditions on the Joined Tables](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-the-joined-tables)